# Change position of year in reference - biblatex biber

Tags: biblatex, biber

Starting from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305539/change-ordering-number-and-year-biblatex) I edited the code presented there to achieve a citation like, `journal-title+volume+pages+year`

```
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
        \printfield{series}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{pages}%
    \setunit{\space (}%
    \usebibmacro{date})%
    \newunit}
```

Could it have been done better? Most likely, I dont know how macros is used but it works as intended with one minor problem. After the year, the pages are added again. I assume it is because the macro `journal+issuetitle` doesn't encompass pages, so try adding `+pages` to the name but it didn't do anything.

Was wondering what needs to be changed in the redefinition of the macros so pages is not shown again at the end.

Pic of how it looks like (there are more editions done to biblatex): 
[image]

Edit:

A working minimal example without the rest of the editions so that is shorter would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, sortcites=true, sorting=none, url=false,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
        \printfield{series}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{pages}%
    \setunit{\space (}%
    \usebibmacro{date})%
    \newunit}

\title{mwe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Lorem ipsum~\cite{sigfridsson} dolor~\cite{worman}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pages are added again, because they are printed by the macro `note+pages` in the driver for `@article`. If you also print the pages in `journal+issuetitle`, you need to suppress the `pages` in `note+pages`.

The redefinition of `journal+issuetitle` below is based on the standard definition from `standard.bbx`. The only change is the added pages printing.

Note that it is usually bad style to have bare parentheses like `(` and `)` in `\setunit`. In my solution below, I used the ready-made macro `issue+date` that adds the parentheses and takes care of a few other things as well.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, 377–395 (1998). doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

---

If you want to understand how these macros work and why other stuff is printed, you should have a look at the bibliography drivers in [`standard.bbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx), most relevant macros that are called there are either defined in [`standard.bbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx) or [`biblatex.def`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def).

In `biblatex` 3.12 the driver for `@article` can be found in [ll. 26-62 of `standard.bbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx#L26-L62). `journal+issuetitle` is in [ll. 746-761](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx#L746-L761) and `note+pages` in [ll. 857-861](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx#L857).